# Recourse against a moved question

Tags: support, questions, etiquette, stack-overflow

What do I do when a question is moved incorrectly?

I asked a question about finding a replacement for the Office Web Components.  I think it was moved just because I mentioned that the Office Web Components break when viewed from  Windows7.

I think my question belongs in Pro Webmasters.  Am I wrong?  If it does belong here, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

I read your question and checked its progress on the StackOverflow (SO)site.

Given the higher activity and the type of users at SO, your question will probably fare better over there. I recently had a question that could have gone in the Webmasters site, but I posted it in SO instead because I wanted a larger audience.

Your question had more development (MSO development) specifics than is normally discussed on the Webmasters site, plus, it had the added detail on Windows7 clients.

I see your point, and also, given the recent splintering out of some of the subject matters this is potentially a recurring theme. For example, there will be much overlap between StackOverflow and the UI site as well as Webmasters and the UI site.

With growth comes a little pain, I suppose. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are obviously times when it is tough to place a question because it sits in that middle ground between to Stack Exchange sites.  .

If you feel strongly that the question should not have been moved your best recourse is to ask the question again on Webmasters and make sure to phrase it in a way that it pertains to the operation of your website and nothing else.